# Binary utilities for Android

Tags: android

`busybox` provides some, but not all, useful binary utilities for Android. For example, there are no `pstree` or `file`. To use these utilities, one must cross-compile them with ARM as target.

Question:

1. Are there any other sources of Android binary utilities?
2. Is there any toolchain for cross-compiling binary utilities on Android (possibly with a guide)? And how to deal with the library issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **BotBrew** !
Binary utilities for Android
http://botbrew.com/
download = > https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inportb.botbrew

Answer (score 0):

[Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) has everything you need to recompile any binary.

Answer (score 0):

[Opkg](http://code.google.com/p/opkg) is a lightweight package management system. It is written in C and resembles apt/dpkg in operation. It is intended for use on embedded Linux devices and is used in this capacity in the OpenEmbedded and OpenWrt projects.

The above-mentioned *botbrew* uses it for packages.